# SharePoint 2010/2013 resource throttling question

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, resource-throttling

As I understand SharePoint **resource throttling** for large sets of items was introduced in SP2010 to safeguard against SQL table locks by massive queries from SharePoint. I have 2 questions about this resource throttling:

1. Are there major (or any at all) changes in resource throttling implementation (default values, the way it is enforced) between SP2010 & SP2013?
2. Doing some test in SharePoint 2013 I noticed that when I create list with 5000+ items I don't see threshold being enforced, but at the same time when I create a library with 5000+ directories it is being enforced. Why is it so?

Can somebody confirm that/share links to documentation which explains this?

Answer (score 4):

There has not been any major changes to the throttling rules.  Things are still set to 5000 items returned unless Admin or certain times (if enabled).  You still are limited to the default 8 lookups.  Basically the settings and how they are enforced hasn't changed.

I have honestly never heard about thresholds not being enforced on a single box installation.  I wouldn't know why you would want to build something that large on a single box anyways.  They only time I have ever used it is for demos and even then, I make sure I have a large enough system to handle a separate SQL server from SP.  If you are hitting the kinds of queries and number of items that start hitting thresholds, you should consider moving to a different architecture.

You aren't using this in a multi-user environment are you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm basically using single test VM which includes almost full MSFT stack in it (Windows Server, SQL, Exchange, SharePoint) and I'm unable to get threshold enforced on this box. I'm creating 5000+ elements list, using regular, non-admin user but anyway user not getting threshold enforcement message...

Comment: That's interesting Mikhail. I have honestly never heard of that.

Comment: Also default list view lookup threshold seems to be increased to 12 in SharePoint 2013 Post June 2013 CU update... I seen this mentioned in SharePoint Escalation Services Team Blog.

Comment: You learn something new every day.  I didn't know that.  I can confirm as we are on Oct 2015 and set at 12.  As for your threshold checks, are you doing this while logged in as an admin?  Admins have a default threshold of 20000.

Comment: I was logged as admin but I used runas for IE with regular user account...

Comment: So I have always found Runas can get a little flaky.  Usually around launching Office documents in SharePoint, but I would rule it out.  Could you login as a regular user and try it out?

Comment: I updated my question, I see that threshold is not being enforced for lists with 5000+ items, but enforced for libraries with 5000+ folders on my test box... What I'm missing?

Comment: I may be reaching here as I can think of only one thing that would force it to be enforced on a doc library and not on your list, but do you by chance have any indexes applied on your List?  If you have a list with indexes and then views that access that index, you may not hit the threshold in your query of the DB.